# Массив методов PHP

Tags: php

Добрый время суток. Подскажите есть ли нормальный механизм в пхп, для создания массива методов. Приблизительно так:

```
$action = [
  'index' => $this->indexAction],
  'about' => $this->aboutAction]
];
```

и вызывать методы в таком формате:

```
$action['index'](5);
```

Comment: если только через `call_user_func` запускать, тогда `['index' => [$this, 'indexAction']]` и `call_user_func($action['index'])`. не пробовал.

Comment: и надо понимать, что такое this в этом случае. можно, правда так `class my {
public function a() { echo "a". "\n"; }
public function b() { echo "b". "\n"; }
}


$arr =  array('a', 'b');

$i = new my();
$i->{$arr[1]}();`

Comment: или создать статический массив в классе `static $names = array('a', 'b');` и `$i->{my::$names[1]}();`

Comment: не очень понимаю эту конструкцию `$i->{$arr[1]}()`

Comment: посмотри, будет непонятно, спросишь https://eval.in/383192

Comment: Я не понимаю вообще что эта за конструкция $myObject->{/*что значит фигурные скобки*/}

Comment: фигурные скобки означают, что нужно вычислить значение переменной внутри скобок - и потом использовать результат как будто это была бы просто строка.  Например, если `$arr[0] = 'indexAction'`, то `$i->{$arr[0]}()` эквивалентно `$i->indexAction()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, это возможно. Начиная с PHP 5.4 вы можете вызывать методы объекта через конструкцию `[$this, 'methodName']`

```
[$this, 'indexAction'](5);
```

Воспользоваться этой конструкцией можно, например, так

```
<?php
class MyClass {
  public function indexAction($id) {
    echo "MyClass::indexAction($id)<br />";
  }
  public function aboutAction($id) {
    echo "MyClass::aboutAction($id)<br />";
  }
  public function call($name, $id = 0){
    $actions = [
      'index' => [$this, 'indexAction'],
      'about' => [$this, 'aboutAction']
    ];
    $actions[$name]($id);
  }
}

$obj = new MyClass();
$obj->call('about', 5); // MyClass::aboutAction(5)
```